# Write to Box<dyn Write>

Tags: rust

Hello I'm new to Rust and I try to write a cli to get to understand the language.

I want my cli to read either stdin or an input file, and write to stout or an output file.

It does something like this to get a BufReader form std or that file.

```rust
impl Cli {
    fn infile(&self) -> Box<dyn BufRead> {
        self.infile.as_ref()
            .map(|path| {
                Box::new(BufReader::new(std::fs::File::open(path).unwrap())) as Box<dyn BufRead>
            })
            .unwrap_or_else(|| {
                Box::new(BufReader::new(std::io::stdin())) as Box<dyn BufRead>
            })
    }

    fn outfile(&self) -> Box<dyn Write> {
        self.outfile.as_ref()
            .map(|path|{
                Box::new(BufWriter::new(std::fs::File::open(path).unwrap())) as Box<dyn Write>
            })
            .unwrap_or_else(|| {
                Box::new(BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout())) as Box<dyn Write>
            })
    }
}
```

However, when I try to write to my outfile

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let cli = Cli::parse();

    let infile = cli.infile();
    let outfile = cli.outfile();
    let logfile = cli.logfile();

    let output = infile.lines()
        .map(|line| line.unwrap_or("".to_string()))
        .map(|line| line.as_bytes())
        .for_each(|line| outfile.write_all(line));

    Ok(())
}
```

```
  --> src/main.rs:68:26
   |
68 |         .for_each(|line| outfile.write_all(line));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `Result<(), Error>`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `Result<(), std::io::Error>`
help: consider using a semicolon here
   |
68 |         .for_each(|line| { outfile.write_all(line); });
   |                          +                        +++
```

However, introducing the semicolon causes a new error.

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    /// ...
    let mut outfile = cli.outfile();
    /// ....
        .for_each(|line| { outfile.write_all(line);});
}
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `line`
  --> src/main.rs:67:21
   |
67 |         .map(|line| line.as_bytes())
   |                     ----^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                     |
   |                     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                     `line` is borrowed here
```

Any suggestions on what would be a good way to write my output to my outfile?

Comment: You can't introduce `.map(|line| line.as_bytes())` as part of the `map` chain because it attempts to return a reference to data passed to the closure (and owned by it). Instead, you will need to remove that `.map()` and call `outfile.write_all(line.as_bytes())`, or just `outfile.write_all(&line)`.

Comment: Also note that `Box<dyn BufRead>` is potentially very inefficient if you need to read byte by byte. It's much better to return a `BufReader<Box<dyn Read>>`, so that the buffer comes before the dynamic dispatch, and that dynamic dispatch is only used when you need to do IO anyway.

Comment: You should use `unwrap_or_default()` instead of `.unwrap_or("".to_string())`so you don't have to create an empty `String` in the `Ok` case.

Comment: @cafce25 Creating an empty string is cheap, but yeah, `unwrap_or_default()` is nicer.

Comment: Note that locked stdin is already buffered, so consider using that instead.

Comment: `for_each()` doesn't have a return value. What do you want `output` to contain?